# Pass string slice to variadic empty interface parameter

Tags: go

A package I am using, gosqlite, has a method with a *variadic* parameter where its type is the *empty interface*.

```
func (s *Stmt) Exec(args ...interface{}) os.Error
```

I can call this fine if explicitly pass individual parameters:

```
statement := blah()
error := statement.Exec("hello", 3.0, true) // works fine
```

However, as the variadic parameter corresponds to placeholders within the `in` operator of my SQL statement's `select`, the number of these placeholders is not known at compile time but dynamically changes at run time depending upon what the user is doing. E.g. I end up with SQL akin to the following if the user enters four values:

```
SELECT * FROM sky WHERE name IN (?,?,?,?)
```

So naturally I would like to call the `Exec` method with a slice of strings:

```
var values []string = getValuesFromUser()
statement := createStatementWithSufficientNumberOfPlaceholders(len(values))
_ := statement.Exec(values...) // compiler doesn't like this
```

This does not compile. I can get around this problem by creating an empty interface slice and copying the references over:

```
values2 := make([]interface{}, len(values))
for index, value := range values { values2[index] = value }
_ := statement.Exec(values2...) // compiler happy but I'm not
```

And this works fine but it feels a bit clunky. I was wondering if there was some trick to be able to pass `values` directly to this function or, failing that, a neater way of converting the string slice to an empty interface one?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to pass a `[]string` directly to a `...interface{}` parameter. Doing this requires a linear time copy (with n + 1 allocations!). If the language hid this from you, it would be a significant hidden cost. Normally, passing a slice to a variadic argument just passes the slice into the function.

As for other ways of doing this, you could make it cleaner by writing a function that takes a `[]string` and returns the corresponding `[]interface{}`. Of course, you'll have to write it again for each `[]T` -> `[]interface{}` conversion you want to do, but its a rather short function, and all that changes is the signature. You could use [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), which comes with an inherent runtime cost, to make the function "generic", such as in:

```
valuesVal := reflect.ValueOf(values)
...
for i := range values2 { values2[i] = valuesVal.Index(i).Interface() }
```

Comment: I've left the conversion code inline at the moment: function seems overkill when I added it. I guess the problem, ultimately, is that Go does not support covariant arrays/slices in the way I am accustomed to in Java and C#, which is perhaps [not a bad thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Arrays_in_C.23_and_Java).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer. And I don't suppose there is one since even built-in and variadic  *copy* and *append* have the same (or compatible concrete) element type "blockhead", but I have two obvious suggestions:

- do not return `[]string` from `getValuesFromUser()` (i.e. pass still unadorned `[]interface{})`,
- on the other type end wrap calls to `statement.Exec()` with a *func* making `[]string` to `[]interface{}` conversion.

Or on the same, third, obvious note extend `type statement` with `Exec(args ...string)`.

P.S. I haven't made any benchmarks myself but I don't think this kind of conversion is highly expensive as interface{} feels like a reference type and compiler is probably doing some dirty trickstery behind the curtain... then again perhaps not, though, I'd be happy, too, to learn of an actual solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, I think it would be more wrong to pass `[]interface{}` from `getValuesFromUser()` than it would be to pay the price of the copy. Regarding extending the type: this is an interesting idea, however with the caveat that Go does not support overloaded functions so it would have to have a different name.

Comment: @PaulRuane don't want to sound too philosophical but I don't see how come it would be wrong, so long as this stays hidden from final user (you can always type cast/assert for future reference). on a similar topic there is also older [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839335/any-sensible-solution-to-the-lack-of-array-slice-covariance-in-go/5370177#5370177) by SteveMcQuark that I found interesting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass a varargs slice of interface{} type like this to the method.

```
var paramArray []interface{}
paramArray = append(paramArray, "test1")
paramArray = append(paramArray, "test2")
varargsFunc(paramArray...)
```