# Does a function have to satisfy the exact signature of a function type?

Tags: go

Consider the following simple go program

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type MyEncoder interface {
    Encode(v interface{}) error
}

type MyEncoderCreator func(io.Writer) *MyEncoder

type MyContainer struct {
    Creator MyEncoderCreator
}

func main() {
    container := Container{
        Creator:json.NewEncoder,
    }

    encoder := container.Creator(os.Stdout)
    encoder.Encode(map[string]string{"key":"value"})
}
```

This program fails to compile with the following error:

```
./main.go:21: cannot use json.NewEncoder (type func(io.Writer) *json.Encoder) as type MyEncoderCreator in field value
```

Why is this? The `json.Encoder` struct has a receiver that satisfies the `MyEncoder` interface. So should the `json.NewEncoder` function be allowed to assigned to `MyContainer.Creator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a function has to satisfy the exact signature of the function type. Similar things come up in other contexts: a more formal way to say it is that generally [types in Go lack covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839335/any-sensible-solution-to-the-lack-of-array-slice-covariance-in-go?rq=1). Here, you could wrap `json.NewEncoder` in a function returning `MyEncoder`.

I'd use the value type `MyEncoder` not the pointer `*MyEncoder` because if you store a pointer *inside* the interface value then generally you don't also need a pointer *to* the interface value just to avoid copies; [here's more on pointers vs. values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970#23551970) if it helps.